What do you think about doubling points earned on questions?
I’ve just received a mail from SO about the decision they made to increase the value of upvotes to questions. 

Starting today, we’re doubling the reputation points earned from
  getting an upvote to a question to 10 points. This makes it equal to
  the reputation points earned from getting an upvote to an answer.

What do you think about this?

Speriamo che perlomeno così ci siano più buone domande su Italian.SE!

@Charo 10.000 punti in un batter d’occhio. Abbiamo una nuova numero 1.

Questo non sembra aver attirato più domande sul sito  :'(

Non ti avevo ancora ringraziato per il tuo commento, ma, adesso che i voti su domande e risposte danno gli stessi punti, possiamo dividere i punti di reputazione di un utente per il numero totale dei post che ha scritto per farci un'idea della qualità media dei post dell'utente giudicata dalla communità. Se lo fate, potete vedere che i miei post sono tra i più cattivi del sito. Quindi, autori dei buoni post, continuate a scrivere qualcosa di tanto in tanto, per carità!

I knew this was coming (moderators were sort-of forewarned) and I have to say I am strongly in favor. Especially for sites like Italian.SE good questions are somewhat more valuable than good answers (which doesn't mean that you all should stop answering questions: you are great) and it always seemed ridiculous to me that questions were rewarded half of what answers were.
Hopefully we won't have the problems that other sites have, people asking a lot of low quality questions suddenly getting a lot of new privileges. For one thing, we never had the problem that low quality questions get too many upvotes...

I guess in the end it all boils down to the specific community's attitude to low-level questions when it comes to up/down voting. Could be a double-edged sword on some sites that have attracted lots of low-quality questions, although many of the latter have with time developed some sort of "antibodies". For example, if one has a look at the main StackOverflow site, I'm personally under the impression that many questions (although on-topic and eventually answered) don't receive upvotes at all. For the ItalianSE, I think this will be positive.
